# Downloading Subarea vs Clipping Images to AOI using Planet API?

Tags: api, planet

This question is associated with the two Planet API tutorials: ["Download a Subarea"](https://developers.planet.com/tutorials/download-a-subarea/) and ["Clip Images to AOI"](https://developers.planet.com/tutorials/clip-images-to-aoi/).

It seems to me that both tutorials demonstrate methods to download only a piece of an image from a large scene so as to increase efficiency.

How do these tutorials differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important distinction is that the Clip API will be decomissioned in favour of other means of downloading parts of images, but the documentation is still there for existing users to reference. Currently, it is recommended that new users employ the subarea method.

Otherwise, you are correct, both allow you do fetch just a piece of an image.