# Catch error of empty response of Planet API

Tags: python, api, planet

I am automating the download of some small polygons of PlanetScope4 images.

It works well, but some times, at a random polygon, it breaks down with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "planet_api/search_asset.py", line 105, in search_images_in_interval
    json_res = search_result.json()
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

It looks like an empty response, not a response of empty features as I find normally.

I tried to catch it like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        search_result = requests.post(
            PLANET_API_SEARCH_URL,
            auth=(PLANET_API_KEY, ''),
            json=search_request)
        json_res = search_result.json()
        break
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        logger.critical("API failed")
        time.sleep(1)
logger.debug(json_res)
```

But the error still happened.

So the questions are: How is the proper way of catching this error? Any idea why this error happens and how to prevent it so I don't need to catch it?

EDIT: 
I just saw that I'm using a not recommended method anymore in this post [Planet API: Download a Subarea vs. Clip Images to AOI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295093/planet-api-download-a-subarea-vs-clip-images-to-aoi).

Will my problem be solved if I change to the Subarea method?

I know there are 3 questions in the same post, but I think all of them point to solve the same specific problem.

Comment: Try printing the response when the JSON decode doesn't work. There will probably be an error message that will indicate what the problem is. Something like printing `search_result.text` in the exception handler should do it.

Comment: Hey! I did and it appears to be a failure of the server, nothing that can be done in my side. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Please post the error that you ran into on the API side and Planet can look into it.

To your other question, it is advisable to move away from the Clip API since it will be decommissioned eventually, although you are more than welcome to use it in the meantime.

Comment: <html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>

This was the error apearing.